# Glitch in top banner

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Just today I noticed a glitch showing up above the Search box in The Workplace banner. It looks like a small strip of the background is covering up the black banner. This occurs at The Workplace and at The Workplace Meta, but I haven't seen it on any other SE sites. It occurs on both Chrome and Firefox for me. I'm running Windows 10. Is this happening for anyone else?

[image: Workplace banner glitch]

[image: Workplace meta banner glitch]

Comment: [Reproducible](http://i.imgur.com/HnzcwMC.png) on all browsers. FF 53.0, IE 11, Chrome 59.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. It's definitely a bug caused by new footer. Fix is waiting in repo for build. Consider it done.

Comment: And now it's gone!